# Qemu top panel (which contains the "Exit full screen" button) doesn't appear in full screen

Tags: linux, qemu, fullscreen

I'm running `libvirt-1.3.5-1` and `qemu-2.6.0-1` on Manjaro **16.0**. Whenever I run a VM full screen, the slider that I once expected to slide down, which would allow me to resume from full screen doesn't show up when I move the mouse over to the top of the window. It's there and active since I can click blindly and — by chance — click the «*Leave Fullscreen*» button but it's just invisible.

BTW none of the tips and tricks mentioned in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43861/how-do-i-unmaximize-full-screen-view-in-virt-manager) work for me. I've tried with two of my virtual machines (one Windows, one Linux Mint) and the issue is the same and I'm assuming it's also true for all (about 10) of them. Is there anything I can do to force this sliding panel to appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of updates later and there is the sliding top panel again with `virt-manager 1.4.0-2`... That obviously was a bug, which is fixed now. Obviously.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to exit full screen from `qemu`.